# Epiphany don't work if you have mixed user locales

Tags: epiphany

Epiphany don't work if you have mixed use locales.

How to reproduce an error:

- Install Elementary OS 6.1 from latest iso.
- In System Settings change Formats to a different language and press button "Set Language"
- Logout

After that Epiphany can't open any site.

If you instead use button "Set System Language", Epiphany works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

[This is an old flatpak bug](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/3712), fixed in flatpak 1.12.0, which was released in October 2021. You might report a bug to ask the elementary OS developers to update flatpak or backport the fix.